# Create new column with function in Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out the new dataframe API in Spark. Seems like a good step forward but having trouble doing something that should be pretty simple.  I have a dataframe with 2 columns, "ID" and "Amount".  As a generic example, say I want to return a new column called "code" that returns a code based on the value of "Amt".  I can write a function something like this:

```
def coder(myAmt:Integer):String {
  if (myAmt > 100) "Little"
  else "Big"
}
```

When I try to use it like this:

```
val myDF = sqlContext.parquetFile("hdfs:/to/my/file.parquet")

myDF.withColumn("Code", coder(myDF("Amt")))
```

I get type mismatch errors

```
found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
required: Integer
```

I've tried changing the input type on my function to org.apache.spark.sql.Column but I then I start getting errors with the function compiling because it wants a boolean in the if statement.

Am I doing this wrong?  Is there a better/another way to do this than using withColumn?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `myDF.printSchema` please, let's see the file table structure.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Let's say you have "Amt" column in your Schema:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val myDF = sqlContext.parquetFile("hdfs:/to/my/file.parquet")
val coder: (Int => String) = (arg: Int) => {if (arg < 100) "little" else "big"}
val sqlfunc = udf(coder)
myDF.withColumn("Code", sqlfunc(col("Amt")))
```

I think withColumn is the right way to add a column

Comment: I've never seen a fucntion written in scala the way you did above.  By extension, If i had a more complex function with multiple arguments, would I write something like: val coder: ((Int, Int) => String) = (arg1: Int, arg2:Int) => {if (arg1 <100 && arg2 <100 .... ?

Comment: @JCalbreath, its a function literal in scala, see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241147/what-is-a-function-literal-in-scala

Comment: is it possible to add column which is Map[String,Any] so I can with custom udf parse json and save it into dataframe as scala's Map collection

Comment: I think in myDF.withColumn("Code", sqlfunc(col("Amt"))) the column data needs to be specified with the dataframe  i.e  myDF.withColumn("Code", sqlfunc(myDF.col("Amt")))

Comment: @YijieShen, could you please help on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55332897/how-to-add-new-column-to-datasetrow-using-map-function-on-the-dataset

Answer (score 17):

We should avoid defining `udf` functions as much as possible due to its overhead of `serialization` and `deserialization` of columns.

You can achieve the solution with simple `when` spark function as below

```
val myDF = sqlContext.parquetFile("hdfs:/to/my/file.parquet")

myDF.withColumn("Code", when(myDF("Amt") < 100, "Little").otherwise("Big"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this:
You can create any function but according to the above error, you should define function as a variable

Example:

```
val coder = udf((myAmt:Integer) => {
  if (myAmt > 100) "Little"
  else "Big"
})
```

Now this statement works perfectly:

```
myDF.withColumn("Code", coder(myDF("Amt")))
```