# Appending a new column to existing CSV file in Spark with Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have found a solution to my problem here [Create new column with function in Spark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219592/create-new-column-with-function-in-spark-dataframe)

But i am having difficulty in converting the below code to Java since it's in Scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val myDF = sqlContext.parquetFile("hdfs:/to/my/file.parquet")
val coder: (Int => String) = (arg: Int) => {if (arg < 100) "little" else "big"}
val sqlfunc = udf(coder)
myDF.withColumn("Code", sqlfunc(col("Amt")))
```

Can someone provide me the Java equivalent code for this?. I am stuck in converting below 2 lines

```
val coder: (Int => String) = (arg: Int) => {if (arg < 100) "little" else "big"}
val sqlfunc = udf(coder)
```

Thanks,

Comment: Well, clearly you would be able to convert some of this. So instead of asking for a code-translation service, please point out which particular bits are causing you a problem.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul, Line 3 & 4 are troubling me, can you please provide  me the translation for that?. Thanks

Comment: Are you using Java 8?

Answer (score 2):

Create your User Defined Function:

```
public class CodeUdf implements  UDF1<Integer, String>{
    @Override
    public String call(Integer integer) throws Exception {
        if(integer < 100)
            return "little";
        else
            return"big";
    }
}
```

Tell Spark about it

```
sqlContext.udf().register("Code", new CodeUdf(), DataTypes.IntegerType);
```

Use it in a select.

```
df.selectExpr("value", "Code(value)").show();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val myDF = sqlContext.parquetFile("hdfs:/to/my/file.parquet")
//val coder: (Int => String) = (arg: Int) => {if (arg < 100) "little" else "big"}
//val sqlfunc = udf(coder)
myDF.selectExpr("Code", "case when Amt < 100 'little' else 'big' end ")
```