# Unable to call spark udf with column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I have this udf in my spark scala code -

```
def calculateConCountFacet(connCount: Long): String = {
        connCount match {
          case c if c >= 0 && c <= 50 => "SIZE_0_TO_50"
          case c if c >= 51 && c <= 200 => "SIZE_51_TO_200"
          case c if c >= 201 && c <= 500 => "SIZE_201_TO_500"
          case c if c >= 501 && c <= 1000 => "SIZE_501_TO_1000"
          case _ => "SIZE_1001_OR_MORE"
        }
      }
```

trying to call it like this -

```
val transformedMemberConnections = testDF.withColumn("test", calculateConCountFacet(col("CNT")))
```

Seeing this error

```
An error was encountered:
<console>:50: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Long
       val transformedMemberConnections = testDF.withColumn("test", calculateConCountFacet(col("CNT")))
                                                                                              ^
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: found the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219592/create-new-column-with-function-in-spark-dataframe