# What is the use of function Types in scala?

Tags: scala

Take below function as example:

```
val increment: (Int) => (Int) = (x) => (x+1)
```

How could this be used as function Type? or more specifically why such implementation is called function Type? How is it more beneficial than the below implementation of function?

```
def increment(x: Int): Int = x + 1
```

Comment: The second one is a method, not a function. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: First, your `def` didn't compile, then, ```scala> increment(_) ==> res1: Int => Int = <function1>```

Comment: I think you got something wrong here. Function Type is the type of the function, in this case Int => Int meaning this is function that takes an Int and returns an Int. Maybe you mean the use of anonymous functions (function literals) compared to normal functions (defined using `def`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a function literal in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241147/what-is-a-function-literal-in-scala)