# Higher Order Function with `Val` and `Def`

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

I am new to `Scala` and trying to explore more in the functional approach.
I have written a method and define a variable like this:-

```
val list = 1 to 10 toList

def getFilterList(list: List[Int],f:Int => Boolean): List[Int] = {
  list.filter(f)
}

getFilterList(list, x => x %2 ==0)

val oddHOF :Int => Boolean = value => value % 2 == 0

list.filter(oddHOF)
```

Now, my Question is that, is both `oddHOF` and `getFilterList` are higher order function if not then what `oddHOF` and `getFilterList` be called ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **[Higher ordered function](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions.html.html)** is a function that takes function as parameter. Hence, `getFilterList` is a higher ordered function since it takes function of type `Int => Boolean` as parameter.

On the other hand, `oddHOF` is **[First class function](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-scala/9781449368814/ch05.html)**, which means you can express functions in function literal syntax. e.g.  `val oddHOF: Int => Boolean = (value:Int) => value % 2 == 0`. Here, the type of function is `Int => Boolean`, i.e. it takes one parameter of type `Int` and return `boolean` value and `(value:Int) => value % 2 == 0` is a [function literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241147/what-is-a-function-literal-in-scala).

Comment: True except that `getFilterList` is a method, not a function (but perhaps that's a bit of needless hair splitting).

Comment: @jwvh what exactly is difference between function and method ?

Comment: @AkashSethi, A topic of much confusion. Discussed at length [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839537/functions-vs-methods-in-scala).