# Error with DefaultValueAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make the DefaultValueAttribute value dynamic, and this is how I'm attempting to accomplish this

```
DefaultValueAttribute(string.Format("Copyright @ 2009 - {0} {1}", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(), "Gods Creation Taxidermy"))]
```

Doing so gives me this error message:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

Is what I'm trying to do just not possible or am I going about it wrong? Any suggestons or ideas?

**EDIT**: Here's the entire property:

```
[CategoryAttribute("Text Settings"),
DescriptionAttribute("Copyright Text..."),
DefaultValueAttribute(string.Format("Copyright @ 2009 - {0} {1}", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(), "Gods Creation Taxidermy"))]        
public string CopyrightText { get; set; }
```

Comment: What are you trying to set the default value of?

Comment: I'm trying to have it say "Copyright @ 2009 - " current year on the watermark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most often, the way attributes are used will prevent this. Only a pure [literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485119/what-does-the-word-literal-mean) constant value, which can be understood *before* compiling really gets underway, can be used in a declarative attribute constructor. Basically only pure numbers, strings, types or enums, with no manipulation.

The exception to this is when the module that is looking at the attributes is compatible with [ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx).

A type that implements ICustomTypeDescriptor can use the [GetAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.getattributes.aspx) method to return a set of attributes created entirely at runtime. This means that not only the state but also the presence of an attribute can be controlled at runtime by the state of your object.

A reminder though: the limitation of this is approach is that not everything that is attribute-driven looks for this interface. In fact, many don't. But it may be worth looking into. One example of a module that *does* make use of ICustomTypeDescriptor is the PropertyGrid control. The use of these together is described here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/bending_property.aspx

Comment: It would be nice if this would work, sure would come in handy, but thanks for the time you put into this for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

As the error clearly states, attribute paramters must be *compile-time* constants.