# What is a "literal" in C++?

Tags: c++, terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the word “literal” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485119/what-does-the-word-literal-mean)

Often when reading literature about C++, I encounter the word "literal". It is a bit unclear to me what exactly this term means in C++.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: **See also:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/485119/what-does-the-word-literal-mean

Comment: Note: Not to be confused with the [C++/CLI `literal` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yzft952.aspx) : "A variable (data member) marked as literal in a /clr compilation is the native equivalent of a static const variable."

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A literal is some data that's presented directly in the code, rather than indirectly through a variable or function call.

Here are some examples, one per line:

```
42
128
3.1415
'a'
"hello world"
```

The data constituting a literal cannot be modified by a program, but it may be copied into a variable for further use:

```
int a = 42;  // creates variable `a` with the same value as the literal `42`
```

[This concept is by no means unique to C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29).

The term "literal" comes from the fact that you've written data [*literally*](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/literally) into your program, i.e. exactly as written, not "hidden" behind a variable name.

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia gives you quickly this about [literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29).

In your C or C++ source code, Things like `1234`, `nullptr` (in recent C++), `"abcd"` are literals.

Comment: `nullptr` is a keyword, no?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: "nullptr: The pointer literal is the keyword nullptr. " (§2.14.7) - appears to be both.