# A char = 1 byte, but why it is stored with 4 bytes?

Tags: c, size, byte

I know this is a stupid question but I don't understand this problem. Could anyone please explain to me?

I know that a char is 1 byte. I created a file sample.txt and fill in `"1234"`
I used fseek and ftell to print the file size. The output is **4 bytes**. This means each of char in the string `"1234"` is **1 byte**.

But when I write like this `printf("%d", sizeof('4'));` The output is 4. So the char `4` is stored with **4 bytes**.

So what are differences between the char `4` that read from the file and char `4` in the source?

*** My question was marked duplicated here:
[Why are C character literals ints instead of chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433895/why-are-c-character-literals-ints-instead-of-chars)

But it is not. The other topic doesn't explain why computer treats the char in the file as 1 byte each.

Comment: This seems not a duplicate. The question you linked didn't answer why computer treat the char in the file with 1 byte. The answer said "More specifically the integral promotions. In K&R C it was virtually (?) impossible to use a character value without it being promoted to int first..." It didn't say why the chars in a file don't need to be promoted.

Comment: Computer doesn’t treat chars in files as anything. It does what you tell it to do. A char is one byte by definition and a character literal is an int by definition, in C. If you write bytes to a file and read them as bytes, they’re bytes. That’s all you, not the computer.

Comment: The problem is that although constants such as `'4'` are actually integer constants (in C; in C++, they are character constants — it is one of many reasons why C and C++ have to be treated as different languages). Granted, the value of a constant such as `'4'` is such that it fits into a `char` variable (and the basic character set — the alphabet, digits, punctuation, white space — must all be positive values), but that doesn't alter the fact that they're integer constants (type `int`). When used in a character string, they're truncated to 1 byte (usually 8 bits) each.

Comment: Read more about literals here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111329/what-is-a-literal-in-c

Comment: The characters inputted from the file are not literals.