# Formatting strings from i18n

Tags: internationalization, rust

Rust's string formatting macros (e.g. "println!" and "format!") require their format string argument to be a string literal (as [observed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734708/println-error-format-argument-must-be-a-string-literal)). Given this, what approach should I use for formatting messages where the text (which will need a additional data embedded into it) needs to come from an external source, e.g. a database of message translations, like a .po file or similar?

Comment: This is an area of Rust that is definitely not mature yet.

Comment: I have been experimenting with that and have some early version https://github.com/pzol/r18n

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, you may wish to reword it. I think that people are getting hung up on the internationalization part of your question, and missing that you are basically asking *"how can I have a dynamic format string?"* Including that you want to do i18n is useful for context, though.

Answer (score 1):

Rust explicitly chose NOT to attempt to address the problem for now.

The issue of internationalization and localization is hairy; there are lots of quirks in natural languages:

- in English, you use the `th` suffix after a number to form a literal, except when it's `st` (after 1 or 21 but not after 11) or `nd` or `rd`
- in Polish, you have relatively complex rules for [plural forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_grammar#Numbers_and_quantifiers)

To the best of my knowledge, no library today addresses the full complexity of what would be needed for a "complete" solution to internationalization in any language. Rust investigation can be [followed here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/822).