# How do I concatenate strings?

Tags: string, rust, string-concatenation

How do I concatenate the following combinations of types:

- `str` and `str`
- `String` and `str`
- `String` and `String`

Comment: Note that `str` and `&str` are *different types* and for 99% of the time, you only should care about `&str`. There are other questions detailing the differences between them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate static strings in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157399/how-to-concatenate-static-strings-in-rust)

Answer (score 719, accepted):

When you concatenate strings, you need to allocate memory to store the result. The easiest to start with is `String` and `&str`:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut owned_string: String = "hello ".to_owned();
    let borrowed_string: &str = "world";
    
    owned_string.push_str(borrowed_string);
    println!("{owned_string}");
}
```

Here, we have an owned string that we can mutate. This is efficient as it potentially allows us to reuse the memory allocation. There's a similar case for `String` and `String`, as `&String` [can be dereferenced as `&str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#deref-methods).

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut owned_string: String = "hello ".to_owned();
    let another_owned_string: String = "world".to_owned();
    
    owned_string.push_str(&another_owned_string);
    println!("{owned_string}");
}
```

After this, `another_owned_string` is untouched (note no `mut` qualifier). There's another variant that *consumes* the `String` but doesn't require it to be mutable. This is an [implementation of the `Add` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Add%3C%26%27_%20str%3E) that takes a `String` as the left-hand side and a `&str` as the right-hand side:

```rust
fn main() {
    let owned_string: String = "hello ".to_owned();
    let borrowed_string: &str = "world";
    
    let new_owned_string = owned_string + borrowed_string;
    println!("{new_owned_string}");
}
```

Note that `owned_string` is no longer accessible after the call to `+`.

What if we wanted to produce a new string, leaving both untouched? The simplest way is to use [`format!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format.html):

```rust
fn main() {
    let borrowed_string: &str = "hello ";
    let another_borrowed_string: &str = "world";
    
    let together = format!("{borrowed_string}{another_borrowed_string}");
    println!("{}", together);
}
```

Note that both input variables are immutable, so we know that they aren't touched. If we wanted to do the same thing for any combination of `String`, we can use the fact that `String` also can be formatted:

```rust
fn main() {
    let owned_string: String = "hello ".to_owned();
    let another_owned_string: String = "world".to_owned();
    
    let together = format!("{owned_string}{another_owned_string}");
    println!("{}", together);
}
```

You don't *have* to use `format!` though. You can [clone one string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#impl-Clone) and append the other string to the new string:

```rust
fn main() {
    let owned_string: String = "hello ".to_owned();
    let borrowed_string: &str = "world";
    
    let together = owned_string.clone() + borrowed_string;
    println!("{together}");
}
```

**Note** - all of the type specification I did is redundant - the compiler can infer all the types in play here. I added them simply to be clear to people new to Rust, as I expect this question to be popular with that group!

Comment: What do you think about `Add` / `+` symbol? You could cover it if you want.

Comment: Maybe that's simple enough, but understanding it requires looking at the possible type signatures for Add with String.

Comment: Thanks! Are you able to go into slightly more depth into how &String can be dereferenced as a &str? Which part of its implemention permits that and/or where does it say this in the doco?

Comment: @jsalter that's a pretty separate topic, so it may be good as another top-level question. I have updated to link to the appropriate docs (as close as I can get, at least...)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan It should be noted that the discrepancy `.to_owned()` and `.to_string()` has been fixed since the above comment thanks to impl specialization. They both now have the same performance when called on a `&str`. Relevant commit: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/32586/files

Comment: The type specifications are definitely helpful in this code.

Comment: Should 2nd sentence 2nd para read '... case for `String` and `&String`...' as it's an edit of less than 6 characters SO won't allow me to make this change! (or could be a more subtle point that I haven't understood)

Comment: @paddyg Yes, it's kind of subtle. The starting types are both `String`, but then you take a reference to one (`&String`) which can be coerced to a `&str`. I put the entire path `String` -> `&String` -> `&str` because beginners may not even realize that you can take a reference to a `String`. :-)

Comment: It would be nice to add `owned_string += borrowed_string` and `owned_string += &another_owned_string` as comments in the first two codeblocks, as they do the same thing.

Answer (score 114):

To concatenate multiple strings into a single string, separated by another character, there are a couple of ways.

The nicest I have seen is using the `join` method on an array:

```
fn main() {
    let a = "Hello";
    let b = "world";
    let result = [a, b].join("\n");

    print!("{}", result);
}
```

Depending on your use case you might also prefer more control:

```
fn main() {
    let a = "Hello";
    let b = "world";
    let result = format!("{}\n{}", a, b);

    print!("{}", result);
}
```

There are some more manual ways I have seen, some avoiding one or two allocations here and there. For readability purposes I find the above two to be sufficient.

Comment: Where is `join` documented? It seems to sit halfway between an Array and a String. I searched through the [array](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html) documentation and was quickly confused.

Comment: @DuaneJ `join` is actually attached to [the `SliceContactExt` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/trait.SliceConcatExt.html). The trait is marked unstable but its methods are stable and [are included in the Prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/#prelude-contents) so they're usable everywhere by default. The team appear to be well aware this trait does not need to exist and I imagine things will change in future with it.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that `join` is more efficient than `s1.to_owned().push_str(s2)` for concatenating two `str`'s as it avoids the second allocation.

Answer (score 93):

### Simple ways to concatenate strings in Rust

There are various methods available in Rust to concatenate strings

### First method (Using `concat!()` ):

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", concat!("a", "b"))
}
```

The output of the above code is :

> ab

---

### Second method (using `push_str()` and `+` operator):

```
fn main() {
    let mut _a = "a".to_string();
    let _b = "b".to_string();
    let _c = "c".to_string();

    _a.push_str(&_b);

    println!("{}", _a);

    println!("{}", _a + &_c);
}
```

The output of the above code is:

> ab
>
> abc

---

### Third method (`Using format!()`):

```
fn main() {
    let mut _a = "a".to_string();
    let _b = "b".to_string();
    let _c = format!("{}{}", _a, _b);

    println!("{}", _c);
}
```

The output of the above code is :

> ab

Check it out and experiment with [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f50feb4d857982551eb462abe3a01acc).

Comment: This answer does not add anything new to the existing answers.

Comment: The answer is nicely formatted, which serves a purpose. It may not add anything new, but I'm glad @ashwin-rajeev boiled it down.

Comment: `concat` only works with literals, so, not super useful.

Answer (score 31):

I think that [`concat`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/std/slice/trait.SliceConcatExt.html#tymethod.concat) method and `+` should be mentioned here as well:

```rust
assert_eq!(
  ("My".to_owned() + " " + "string"),
  ["My", " ", "string"].concat()
);
```

and there is also [`concat!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/std/macro.concat!.html) macro but only for literals:

```rust
let s = concat!("test", 10, 'b', true);
assert_eq!(s, "test10btrue");
```

Comment: `+` is already mentioned in an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30154791/155423). (*This is an implementation of the `Add` trait that takes a `String` as the left-hand side and a `&str` as the right-hand side:*)

Comment: True, _existing answer_ is so broad I didn't notice though.

Comment: Best answer so far. Just use array method or concat for strings. Macros are just handy for hiding some syntax rather than inventing complex syntax making core language cryptic. Add trait could be nice for objects but can be confusing at least.

Answer (score 26):

### Concatenation by String Interpolation

UPDATE: As of 2021, Dec 28, this is available in Rust 1.58 Beta. You no longer need Rust Nightly build to do String Interpolation. (Leaving remainder of answer unchanged for posterity).

RFC 2795 issued 2019-10-27:
Suggests support for implicit arguments to do what many people would know as "string interpolation" -- a way of embedding arguments within a string to concatenate them.

RFC: https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2795-format-args-implicit-identifiers.html

Latest issue status can be found here:
https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/67984

At the time of this writing (2020-9-24), I believe this feature should be available in the Rust Nightly build.

This will allow you to concatenate via the following shorthand:

```
format_args!("hello {person}")
```

It is equivalent to this:

```
format_args!("hello {person}", person=person)
```

There is also the "ifmt" crate, which provides its own kind of string interpolation:

https://crates.io/crates/ifmt

Comment: Now this is available in Rust 1.58 Beta.

Answer (score 10):

Concat two `String`:

```
fn concat_string(a: String, b: String) -> String {
    a + &b
}
```

Concat two `&str`:

```
fn concat_str(a: &str, b: &str) -> String {
    a.to_string() + b
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Rust 1.58, you can also concatenate two or more variables like this: `format!("{a}{b}{c}")`. That's basically the same as `format!("{}{}{}", a, b, c)`, but a bit shorter and (arguably) easier to read. Those variables can be `String`, `&str` (and also other non-string types for that matter). The result is a `String`.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70504075) for more.

Answer (score -3):

By Default in Rust is all about MemoryManage and Owenership and Move, we dont see usually like copy or deep copy hence
*if you are trying to concatinate strings then left hand side should type String which is growable and should be mutable type, the right hand side can be normal string literal a.k.a type String slices*

```
    fn main (){
            let mut x = String::from("Hello"); // type String
            let y = "World" // type &str
            println!("data printing -------> {}",x+y);



}
```

**official statement from doc, this is pointing to when you are trying using arthmatic + operator**
[image]

Answer (score -10):

```
fn main() {
    let a = String::from("Name");
    let b = "Pkgamer";
    println!("{}",a+b)
}
```

Comment: In case you're wondering why you're getting downvoted: You're not providing any explanatory text, your answer doesn't address the question fully (what about the three combinations of `&str`/`String`?), and your answer doesn't add much over e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55581111/401059).