# Why is it not possible to concatenate two Strings in Rust without taking a reference to one of them?

Tags: rust

This works:

```
let hello = "Hello ".to_string();
let world = "world!";

let hello_world = hello + world;
```

But this doesn't:

```
let hello = "Hello ".to_string();
let world = "world!".to_string();

let hello_world = hello + world;
```

But this does:

```
let hello = "Hello ".to_string();
let world = "world!".to_string();

let hello_world = hello + &world;
```

Is that because the `String` needs a pointer to the original string slice of the second `String`? If so, why?

Comment: And to be clear, it's [**absolutely possible to concatenate two Strings without Deref coercion**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30154541/155423).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is in two parts.

---

The first part is that `+` involves using [an `Add` trait implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html). It is implemented only for:

```
impl<'a> Add<&'a str> for String
```

Therefore, string concatenation only works when:

- the Left Hand Side is a `String`
- the Right Hand Side is coercible to a `&str`

*Note: unlike many other languages, addition will consume the Left Hand Side argument.*

---

The second part, therefore, is what kind of arguments can be used when a `&str` is expected?

Obviously, a `&str` can be used as is:

```
let hello = "Hello ".to_string();
let hello_world = hello + "world!";
```

Otherwise, a reference to a type implementing `Deref<&str>` will work, and it turns out that `String` does so `&String` works:

```
let hello = "Hello ".to_string();
let world = "world!".to_string();

let hello_world = hello + &world;
```

---

And what of other implementations? They all have issues.

- `impl<'a> Add<String> for &'a str` requires prepending, which is not as efficient as appending
- `impl Add<String> for String` needlessly consume two arguments when one is sufficient
- `impl<'a, 'b> Add<&'a str> for &'b str` hides an unconditional memory allocation

In the end, the asymmetric choice is explained by Rust philosophy of being explicit as much as possible.

Or to be more explicit, we can explain the choice by checking the algorithmic complexity of the operation. Assuming that the left-hand side has size M and the right-hand side has size N, then:

- `impl<'a> Add<&'a str> for String` is O(N) (amortized)
- `impl<'a> Add<String> for &'a str` is O(M+N)
- `impl<'a, 'b> Add<&'a str> for &'b str` is O(M+N)
- `impl Add<String> for String` is O(N) (amortized)... but requires allocating/cloning the right-hand side for nothing.

Answer (score 4):

The [standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) implements the following:

```
impl<'a> Add<&'a str> for String
```

Which is exactly what you have noticed, you can only add a `&str` to a `String`.

This has these Advantages:

- Use a `&str` slice
- Use a `&String` (as it dereferences to &str)
- Keep the old String (that has been added)