# Why can't I collect strings from a Vec<String> after calling `push` on them?

Tags: rust

I am trying to collect vector of string to string with separator `$`.

```
let v = [String::from("bump"), String::from("sage"),String::from("lol"), String::from("   kek   ")]; 
let s: String = v.into_iter().map(|x| x.push_str("$")).collect();
println!("{:?}",s );
```

The code above does not work, but this:

```
let v = [String::from("hello"), String::from("world"),String::from("shit"), String::from("   +15   ")]; 
let s: String = v.into_iter().collect();
println!("{:?}",s );
```

is working. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post any errors or evidence on why the code isn't working.

Comment: You can also simply use `v.join("$")`. See my updated answer.

Comment: [How do I concatenate strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41688369/155423)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't working because `push_str()` does **not** return the string.

So your `map()` function maps from `String` to `()`, because you don't return `x` from it.

Further, `x` is not mutable, so you cannot call `push_str()` on it. You have to declare it `mut`.

This is your code, minimally modified so that [it works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fc9c333c5166ca6cc4dced05cbf724d3):

```rust
fn main(){
    let v = [String::from("bump"), String::from("sage"),String::from("lol"), String::from("   kek   ")]; 
    let s: String = v.into_iter().map(|mut x| {x.push_str("$"); x}).collect();
    println!("{:?}",s );
}
```

```
"bump$sage$lol$   kek   $"
```

Further, if you only push a single character, do `push('$')` instead.

You will notice, however, that there is a `$` at the end of the string. Your usecase is perfect for `reduce()`, so I'd use @Aleksander's answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

You must return strings from your map.

Note that `push_str` doesn't return anything.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=50534d454a46093299ce38682733c86a

```rs
fn main() {
    let v = [
        String::from("bump"),
        String::from("sage"),
        String::from("lol"),
        String::from(" kek "),
    ];
    let s: String = v
        .iter()
        .map(|x| {
            let mut x = x.to_owned();
            x.push_str("$");
            x
        })
        .collect();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

EDIT

If your real use case is more complex and you must use a iterator and a map, you should prefer above answers which are better done (no need to own the returned strings from the map because you collect them into a new string anyway).

But that said if the only purpose is to join your Vec with a separator you should simply do

```rs
fn main() {
    let v = [
        String::from("bump"),
        String::from("sage"),
        String::from("lol"),
        String::from(" kek "),
    ];
    
    println!("{}", v.join("$"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Iterator::reduce](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.reduce). Note that it will put separators only *between* items (and not at the end of string like in [Petterrabit's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18242865/peterrabbit) answer) and it will re-use the allocation of fist string (which results in slightly better memory efficiency).

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = [
        String::from("bump"),
        String::from("sage"),
        String::from("lol"),
        String::from(" kek "),
    ];
    let s: String = v
        .into_iter()
        .reduce(|mut acc, x| {
            acc.push('$');
            acc.push_str(&x);
            acc
        })
        .unwrap_or_default();
    println!("{}", s);
}
```

Comment: @Finomnis good call. Updated answer.