# How do I insert a dynamic byte string into a vector?

Tags: rust

I need to create packet to send to the server. For this purpose I use vector with `byteorder` crate. When I try to append string, Rust compiler tells I use unsafe function and give me an error.

```
use byteorder::{LittleEndian, WriteBytesExt};

fn main () {
    let login = "test";
    let packet_length = 30 + (login.len() as i16);

    let mut packet = Vec::new();
    packet.write_u8(0x00);
    packet.write_i16::<LittleEndian>(packet_length);
    packet.append(&mut Vec::from(String::from("game name ").as_bytes_mut()));

    // ... rest code
}
```

The error is:

```
packet.append(&mut Vec::from(String::from("game name ").as_bytes_mut()));
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ call to unsafe function
```

This is playground to reproduce: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=381c6d14660d47beaece15d068b3dc6a

What is the correct way to insert some string as bytes into vector ?

Comment: *A* solution is to call the function in an unsafe context, but the *real* solution is to find a way to do what you want in safe Rust. `as_bytes_mut` is unsafe because a `String` is always *always* __*always*__ assumed  to be valid UTF-8, and modifying the byte array directly could break that promise. Do you *need* mutable access to the byte array?

Comment: If you don’t need mutable access (and I don’t think the snippet you included requires it), you can use `as_bytes`, which is perfectly safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unsafe function called was [`as_bytes_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.as_bytes_mut). This creates a mutable reference with *exclusive* access to the bytes representing the string, allowing you to modify them. You do not really need a mutable reference in this case, `as_bytes()` would have sufficed.

However, there is a more idiomatic way. `Vec<u8>` also functions as a writer (it implements `std::io::Write`), so you can use one of its methods, or even the `write!` macro, to write encoded text on it.

```
use std::io::Write;
use byteorder::{LittleEndian, WriteBytesExt};

fn main () -> Result<(), std::io::Error> {
    let login = "test";
    let packet_length = 30 + (login.len() as i16);
    let mut packet = Vec::new();
    packet.write_u8(0x00)?;
    packet.write_i16::<LittleEndian>(packet_length)?;
    let game_name = String::from("game name");
    write!(packet, "{} ", game_name)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e950678bac1d6e910755ef2f091af815)

See also:

- [Use write! macro with a string instead of a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637499/use-write-macro-with-a-string-instead-of-a-string-literal)
- [What's the de-facto way of reading and writing files in Rust 1.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192956/whats-the-de-facto-way-of-reading-and-writing-files-in-rust-1-x)

Comment: With the write macros do we not need to keep track of the current position in the vector? Or what is doing that for you?

Comment: @uriDium The implementation of `Write` for `Vec<u8>` appends incoming bytes to the end of the vector, which is known by the vector value itself. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Write-for-Vec%3Cu8%2C%20A%3E

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.extend()` on the `Vec` and pass in the bytes representation of the `String`:

```rust
use byteorder::{LittleEndian, WriteBytesExt};

fn main() {
    let login = "test";
    let packet_length = 30 + (login.len() as i16);
    let mut packet = Vec::new();
    packet.write_u8(0x00);
    packet.write_i16::<LittleEndian>(packet_length);
    let string = String::from("game name ");
    packet.extend(string.as_bytes());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4499b3758efff380983b8c0ba4c00af8)