# Parameter not living long enough when passing a string to `panic!`

Tags: vector, rust

The parameter `ln` doesn't live long enough, and I couldn't seem to find a reason why it does. I tried to make it and the value I was giving it as input static, but that just caused other problems.

```
pub fn CompileLine(ln: &str) -> std::vec::Vec<u8> {
    let mut out = std::vec::Vec::new();
    let splitLn: Vec<&str> = ln.split_whitespace().collect();
    match splitLn[0] {
        "exit" => out.push(0),
        "reg" => out.push(0x1),
        "rem" => out.push(0x2),
        "set" => out.push(0x3),
        "sum" => out.push(0x4),
        "jmp" => out.push(0x5),
        _ => panic!(splitLn[0]),
    }
    return out;
}
```

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:3:33
  |
3 |     let splitLn: Vec<&str> = ln.split_whitespace().collect();
  |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the function body at 1:1...
 --> src/main.rs:1:1
  |
1 | / pub fn CompileLine(ln: &str) -> std::vec::Vec<u8> {
2 | |     let mut out = std::vec::Vec::new();
3 | |     let splitLn: Vec<&str> = ln.split_whitespace().collect();
4 | |     match splitLn[0] {
... |
13| |     return out;
14| | }
  | |_^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:3:30
  |
3 |     let splitLn: Vec<&str> = ln.split_whitespace().collect();
  |                              ^^
  = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `&str` will meet its required lifetime bounds
 --> src/main.rs:11:14
  |
11|         _ => panic!(splitLn[0]),
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`panic!` takes a string literal as its first argument<sup>1</sup>. A string literal is a `&'static str`, but your string slices are not `'static`.

Instead, pass the string as a formatter argument:

```
panic!("{}", split_ln[0]),
```

It's also worth pointing out:

1. Variables and functions in Rust use `snake_case`.
2. There's no reason to collect the result of `split_whitespace` into a vector unless you plan on iterating over it twice (and maybe not even then).
3. Don't loop over an iterator to push into a `Vec`, you can just `map` and `collect`.
4. There's no need to use `return`, just let the last expression be the value.

```
pub fn compile_line(ln: &str) -> std::vec::Vec<u8> {
    ln.split_whitespace()
        .map(|p| match p {
            "exit" => 0,
            "reg" => 0x1,
            "rem" => 0x2,
            "set" => 0x3,
            "sum" => 0x4,
            "jmp" => 0x5,
            _ => panic!("Unknown mnemonic {}", p),
        })
        .collect()
}
```

See also:

- [println! error: expected a literal / format argument must be a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27734708/155423)

---

<sup>1</sup> This is a dirty lie that I've used because it's easier to understand. If you look at the definition of [`panic!`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.24.1/src/libstd/macros.rs#L64-L78), you'll see that this invocation is actually calling the hidden / internal function [`::rt::begin_panic`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.24.1/src/libstd/panicking.rs#L530):

```
pub fn begin_panic<M: Any + Send>(msg: M, file_line_col: &(&'static str, u32, u32)) -> ! { /* ... */ }
```

Thus the first argument to `panic!` can actually be anything that implements the [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) trait. The `Any` trait requires that any type that implements it must be `'static`:

```
pub trait Any: 'static { /* ... */ }
```

At this point, the same logic applies: you are passing a `&str` and an arbitrary `&str` does not meet the trait bound `'static`.

Comment: Technically, the single-argument version of `panic!` takes anything that is `Any + Send`. Of course, `Any` implies `'static`. Which means it implies `&str: 'static`, thus leading to the compiler's confusing lifetime deduction error.

Comment: `panic!` also takes arbitrary values (not just strings), but the value must be valid forever (because may be shown to the user after all the functions have finished). What `panic!("{}", splitLn[0])` does is it copies `splitLn[0]` into a fresh `String` that can be passed around. Remember the `ln: &str` argument isn't actually a string, it just points to a string that may disappear sometime after the function finishes.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I didn't really want to get into those details because this is likely going to be a problem that people new to Rust will experience, but now I suppose I need to muddle it up.