# How to store large string literals to be used with the format macro without littering code?

Tags: string, rust, formatting, literals

I have a function in my library that takes some variables and returns an HTML page with those variables inserted. What is the best practice not to litter my module with a large HTML literal? I mean that when I read my code it just "doesn't seem right" to have a piece of HTML that I have to scroll through.

I use the `format!` macro with "{}" in places in the literal where I want insert variables so I guess that keeping the page as a file and loading it wouldn't work. I don't have to use `format!` macro, but it seems elegant to not process text manually when I have this kind of tool.

Would creating an entire module just to hold this page be a good practice? In my mind a module is something "bigger", but maybe that's the best thing to do?

Comment: Please define "litter", ideally with some objective metrics. What is "litter" to you might not be to other people, and it's a shame if someone tries to help you only to also "litter". Providing an example of what code you have (with a truncated literal!) is likely to also help.

Comment: It'd be good to state what *hard constraints* you have. Are you requiring that specifically the `format` macro be used?

Comment: `format!` seems to be the wrong tool to generate large pieces of HTML.

Comment: @mcarton how is that wrong?

Comment: @Shepmaster it's hard to provide objective metrics as the question is rather about practices and appearance of code

Comment: @janqo at the very least you'd want a tool that understands HTML escaping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the HTML in an external file and include it via [`std::include_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html). For example

```rust
let html_code = format!(include_str!("src/index.html"), my, values, in, the, template);
```

A playground application doesn't quite work here due to the compile-time requirement of the file, but locally the following worked:

```
src/
    foo.txt -- "{}"
    main.rs -- println!(include_str!("foo.txt"), 1234);
```

Comment: *I use the `format!` macro with "{}" in places in the literal* — please demonstrate how that would work with your solution. See also [println! error: expected a literal / format argument must be a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27734708/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster it in fact does work, I tested it locally and is reflected in my edit.