# Why can't I use println with a str?

Tags: rust

Prologue: I'm at my first day on Rust here.

This is my demo code:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    println!(Move::X.to_string());
}

enum Move {
    Empty,
    X,
    O,
}

impl Move {
    fn to_string(&self) -> &'static str {
        match self {
            Move::Empty => "Empty",
            Move::X => "X",
            Move::O => "O"
        }
    }
}
```

This is not compiling because of these errors

[image]

I kindly ask you a fix, but mainly I need an explanation.

I tried
`println!(String::from(Move::X.to_string()));`
but the error is identical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [println! error: expected a literal / format argument must be a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27734708/println-error-expected-a-literal-format-argument-must-be-a-string-literal)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `println!` is a macro in where the first term expects a string literal. That string literal is evaluated in compile time (so it can never be a reference to actual data).

You can use the newly added formatting string:

```rust
let x = Move::X.to_string();
println!("{x}");
```

or the usual formatting **as the error message suggest you to do**:

```rust
println!("{}", Move::X.to_string())
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e1ddf87500e9ee2b3402adeae84eef4a)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the content of the formatting string literal is evaluated at *compile time*, making it obvious that it can never be a reference to actual data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Move::X.to_string(): String`, not `Move::X.to_string(): &str` or `Move::X.to_string(): str`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str) for an explanation. So even if `println!` did accept a `&str`, it's not by building a `String` that you would solve that issue (even though when calling a function that requires a `&str`, Rust can `Deref` `String` to a `&str` — but `println!` is not a function).

Second, the `println!` macro always and only wants a string literal as its first "argument". That's because it must be able to know at compile time what is the formatting required.