# Rust: Format arguments in the file contents

Tags: rust

I have a simple file, in which I want to add some value from rust in the place of `{}` holders. Is there a way to mimic passing the `content` variable like if the string is hardcoded there? If not, how can I achieve a basic templating system with built-in rust features?

- file.txt:

```
Hello this is from rust: {}
```

- Rust code:

```
use std::fs;
let mut content = fs::read_to_string("file.txt").unwrap().as_mut_str();
format!(content, "SDSD");
```

Rust is giving me this error:

```
format argument must be a string literal rustc
main.rs(17, 13): you might be missing a string literal to format with: `"{} {}",
```

- Cargo check:

```
error: format argument must be a string literal
  --> src\main.rs:17:13
   |
17 |     format!(content, "SDSD");
   |             ^^^^^^^
   |
help: you might be missing a string literal to format with
   |
17 |     format!("{} {}", content, "SDSD");
   |             ++++++++

error: could not compile `web_server` due to previous error
```

### Edit:

I know that format requires a string literal, like I asked above, I wanted to know if there is a way that can **"mimic"** a variable reference as a string literal.
The question there asks for the solution to this error (just use `format!("{}", contents)`), which is not the solution of this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [println! error: expected a literal / format argument must be a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27734844/401059). There's crates for this, though, `runtime_fmt`, e.g.

Comment: The format! macro can't work that way. You may prefer to use someting like `Regex::replace` for this kind of pattern. See https://docs.rs/regex/1.6.0/regex/struct.Regex.html#method.replace

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question [How can I use a dynamic format string with the format! macro?](/q/32572486/2189130)

Comment: Or, if your file is available at compile-time, you can use [`include_str!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include_str.html) to get it as a string literal.