Using ufmt::uwriteln! within a function
I am using rust with #![no_std]. I want to use ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "Hello world\r").unwrap(); in function. I need to pass &mut serial to this function, but don't know how to declare the parameter.
I working on a Arduino Nano and am trying to use ufmt::writeln which says to read ufmt::write which has examples how to use it.
This is how I created the project:
$ cargo generate --git https://github.com/Rahix/avr-hal-template.git
   Project Name: print-fn-test
...
   Generating template ...
✔    Which board do you use? · Arduino Nano
...
✨   Done! New project created ...

This is my current main.rs:
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use panic_halt as _;

use arduino_hal::hal::port::{PD0, PD1};
use arduino_hal::hal::Atmega;
use arduino_hal::pac::USART0;
use arduino_hal::port::mode::{Input, Output};
use arduino_hal::port::Pin;
use arduino_hal::prelude::*;

fn get_type_of<T>(_: &T) -> &'static str where T: ?Sized, {
    core::any::type_name::<T>()
}

// https://docs.rs/ufmt/0.2.0/ufmt/trait.uWrite.html
// fn print_string(serial: &mut arduino_hal::Usart<Atmega, USART0, Pin<Input, PD0>>, s: &str) {
//     ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, &s).unwrap();
// }

#[arduino_hal::entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let dp = arduino_hal::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let pins = arduino_hal::pins!(dp);
    let mut serial = arduino_hal::default_serial!(dp, pins, 57600);
    let mut led = pins.d13.into_output();

    arduino_hal::delay_ms(1000);
    ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "Hello world\r").unwrap();
    ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "{}\r", get_type_of(&mut serial)).unwrap();

    // print_string(&mut serial, "Hello fn!\r");

    loop {
        led.toggle();
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(1000);
    }
}

The program compile and show Hello world and show what type &mut serial is: avr_hal_generic::usart::Usart<atmega_hal::Atmega, avr_device::devices::atmega328p::USART0, avr_hal_generic::port::Pin<avr_hal_generic::port::mode::Input, atmega_hal::port::PD0>, avr_hal_generic::port::Pin<avr_hal_generic::port::mode::Output, atmega_hal::port::PD1>, avr_hal_generic::clock::MHz16> 
But even with all that information I can't figure out how to define fn print_string(...) {}

Your main question is easy: serial: impl uWrite. But you can't pass &s to uwriteln for the same reason you can't pass it to std's format macros: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27734708/6274355

@drewtato Well, the question is about using ufmt::writeln! within a function. Let's say I don't pass &s. With fn print_string(serial: &mut impl uWrite) {ufmt::uwriteln!(serial, "Hello fn").unwrap();} I can't call "unwrap()". How do I deal with that?

@drewtato I got it. Tested it on hardware too. If you want you can post this as an answer. Without passing a string the following works: fn print_string<U: uWrite>(serial: &mut U) where U: uWrite<Error = Infallible>{ufmt::uwriteln!(serial, "Hello fn").unwrap();}

If you want to write a dynamic input string, you should be able to do ufmt::writeln!(serial, "{}", s) (assuming you pass in s: &str) since it's meant to mimic the way core::write! works which allows string formatting.

The hint in the question comments to use serial: impl uWrite in the parameter declaration pushed me in the right direction.
With the help of cargo check and finally also cargo clippy I came up with that solution:
main.rs
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use panic_halt as _;

use ufmt::uWrite;
use core::convert::Infallible;

fn print<U>(serial: &mut U) where U: uWrite<Error = Infallible>{
    ufmt::uwriteln!(serial, "Hello fn").unwrap();
}

fn print_string<U>(serial: &mut U, s: &str) where U: uWrite<Error = Infallible>{
    ufmt::uwriteln!(serial, "Hello fn: {}", s).unwrap();
}

#[arduino_hal::entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let dp = arduino_hal::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let pins = arduino_hal::pins!(dp);
    let mut serial = arduino_hal::default_serial!(dp, pins, 57600);
    let mut led = pins.d13.into_output();

    arduino_hal::delay_ms(1000);
    ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "Hello world\r").unwrap();

    print(&mut serial);
    print_string(&mut serial, "Parameter");
    ufmt::uwriteln!(&mut serial, "end\r").unwrap();

    loop {
        led.toggle();
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(1000);
    }
}

Should https://github.com/Rahix/avr-hal-template.git change, this is the cargo.toml I've used:
[package]
name = "print-fn-test"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["MadMike"]
edition = "2021"
license = "MIT OR Apache-2.0"

[[bin]]
name = "print-fn-test"
test = false
bench = false

[dependencies]
panic-halt = "0.2.0"
ufmt = "0.2.0"
nb = "1.1.0"
embedded-hal = "1.0"

[dependencies.arduino-hal]
git = "https://github.com/rahix/avr-hal"
rev = "3e362624547462928a219c40f9ea8e3a64f21e5f"
features = ["arduino-nano"]

# The latest releases of `proc-macro2` do not support the rust toolchain that
# we use.  Thus, we must fix this dependency to an older version where our
# toolchain is still supported.  See https://github.com/Rahix/avr-hal/issues/537
[build-dependencies.proc-macro2]
version = "=1.0.79"

# Configure the build for minimal size - AVRs have very little program memory
[profile.dev]
panic = "abort"
lto = true
opt-level = "s"

[profile.release]
panic = "abort"
codegen-units = 1
debug = true
lto = true
opt-level = "s"

