# Why a function can be a literal and a expression can't?

Tags: literals

I understand that the concept *literal* is applied to whenever you represent a **fixed value** in source code, exactly as it is meant to be interpreted, vs. a variable or a constant, which are **names** for several of a class or one of them respectively.

But they are also opposed to expressions. I thought it was because they could incorporate variables. But even expressions like `1+2` are not (see first answer in [What does the word "literal" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/485119/3288380)).

So, when I define a variable this way:

```
var=1+2
```

`1+2` is not a literal even though it is not a name and evaluates to a single value. I could then guess that it is because it doesn't represent the target value directly; in other words, a literal represents a value "**exactly as it is**".

But then how is it possible that a function like this one is a literal (as pointed it the same linked answer)?

```
(x) => x*x
```

Comment: The notion of literal and of expression vary from one programming language to another (not the same in Common Lisp and in Ocaml and in C)

Answer (score 1):

Only anonymous functions can be literal because they are not bound to an identifier
so (x)=>x*x is a literal because it is a anonymous function,or function literal
but a

```
void my_func()
{#something}
```

is not  a literal cause it is bound to an identifier;
read these,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function

Answer (score 1):

Expressions can be divided into two general types: atomic expressions and composite expressions.

Composite expressions can be divided by operator, and so on; atomic expressions can be divided into variables, constants, and literals. I guess different authors might use other categories or boundaries here, so it might not be universal. But I will argue why this categorization might make sense.

It's fairly obvious why strings or numbers are literals, or why a sum isn't. A function call can be considered composite, as it operates on subexpressions - its parameters. A function definition does not operate on subexpressions. Only when the so defined function is called, that call passes parameters into the function. In a compiled language, the anonymous function will likely be replaced by a target address where the corresponding code is located - that memory location is obviously not dependent on any subexpression.

@rdRahul's answer references [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_%28computer_programming%29), which says that object literals, such as `{"cat", "dog"}` can be considered literals. This can be easily argued by pointing out that the object which is the value of the expression is just one opaque thing, such as a pointer to the memory location of the object.