# Various ways of creating std::vector on the fly and passing it to another function

Tags: c++, vector, parameter-passing, semantics, literals

I am trying out the various ways of creating `std::vector` on the fly and passing it to another function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void print(std::vector<int> a)
{
    std::cout << a.size() << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    print({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    print(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
    print(std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
}
```

This produces the desired output:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp && ./a.out
5
5
5
```

I want to know what are the differences between these three invocations:

```
print({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
print(std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
print(std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
```

Here is another example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    // std::cout << (a == {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) << '\n'; // error
    std::cout << (a == std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) << '\n';
    std::cout << (a == std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})) << '\n';
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp && ./a.out 
1
1
```

I am hoping that the answer to this question can become a reference answer on this topic where the answer discusses the following aspects of these invocations:

- The above three and any other similar ways of passing a
  `std::vector` to another function.
- Semantic differences between the various methods.
- Performance differences (if any) between the various methods.
- Best practices (if any) due to which one invocation is favourable
  over another.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm not sure about the exact terminology, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485119/what-does-the-word-literal-mean) that can be considered a literal.

Comment: There are no vector "literals". What's happening is standard [*list-initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), using [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) with a suitable [`std::vector` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: I'm sure I recall a very similar question to this last week?

Comment: @user202729 this is a C++ question, that is a C# question. They are quite different languages despite having superficially similar names

Comment: @M.M [tag:language-agnostic] ?

Answer (score 4):

Since C++17, all of these have exactly the same effect. The `print` function is called and the function argument is created by invoking the constructor [`vector(std::initializer_list<int>)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

The first one would probably be considered the preferable syntax since it avoids redundancy.

Prior to C++17 there might have been various temporary objects created and destroyed but that is all in the past now.

Comment: Do they have the same effect in the following scenario too: `std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; std::cout << (a == std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) << '\n'; std::cout << (a == std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})) << '\n';`?

Comment: @LoneLearner yes