# Formatting a const string in Rust

Tags: rust

I don't understand why Rust does not allow to format a const string. This program does not compile:

```
const CON: &str = "test {}";

fn main() {
    println!(CON, 4);
}
```

It generates the following error:

```
error: format argument must be a string literal
 --> a.rs:4:14
  |
4 |     println!(CON, 4);
  |              ^^^
help: you might be missing a string literal to format with
  |
4 |     println!("{} {}", CON, 4);
  |              ^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I read around that `println!` and `format!` only work when the first argument is a string literal. But a `const` string *is* a named string literal.

Comment: `"test {}"` is a string literal. `CON` is not a literal, it's a constant that happens to be set to a literal. See also [Literal (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming))

Comment: And [What does the word "literal" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485119/what-does-the-word-literal-mean)