# Is there a one-step type conversion from String to Vec<u32>?

Tags: rust, type-conversion

I have a file containing prime numbers that I'm unpacking into a `u32` vector. I'm curious if I can do this in one step. If I unpack contents into a `str` vector, then an `u32` vector, everything's dandy.

If I try to move everything into a `u32` vector as I try to do in 
`v_int2`, I get the error that

`|&x| doesn't have a known size at compile time.`

My current understanding is that `&str` has a known size at compile time, since `&str` are written into the binary. Skipping this step means I'm parsing from `String` to `u32`, and I need to inform the compiler about something having to do with the size of my elements. I'm not aware of a way around this, though I'm new in Rust town.

```
let mut file = File::open("first10kprimes.txt")?;
let mut contents = String::new();
file.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;

let v_str = contents.split_whitespace().collect::<Vec<&str>>(); // I just discovered I could do that typing after collect, was a lil jazzed
let v_int: Vec<u32> = v_str.iter().map(|&x| x.parse::<u32>().unwrap()).collect();

let v_int2: Vec<u32> = contents
    .split_whitespace()
    .map(|&x| x.parse().unwrap())
    .collect();
```

Comment: *since `&str` are written into the binary* — this is incorrect. Only string **literals** are in the binary.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=23df7821f1573d01247cd44fb2ae0119).

Comment: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6a29665670ccd69d27e7e657f3d5d9e3

Comment: You already have most of the solution. You just need to remove the `&` in your closure: `.map(|x| x.parse().unwrap())`

Comment: The code posted in this question is inefficient as it builds up a needless intermediate vector (`Vec<&str>`). It's better to chain the iterators.

Comment: @Shepmaster: damn, the Rust god of stack overflow is fast. I think I misunderstand; &str == string literal? I thought this to be true. I'm aware the code is inefficient, and was asking about how to make it better.

Comment: @Jmb, thanks, that does it!

Comment: All string literals are `&str`; not all `&str` are string literals. [What does the word “literal” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/485119/155423)