# The definition of the literal

Tags: python, java, c++, computer-science

When we do some operation on a variable, we just change pointer to another literal? I am a bit confused understanding the exact meaning of the term 'literal'.

Suppose we have int x = 3; // 3 is literal and immutable , x is variable

Doing operation for ex: x++

And now x == 4; so our var x is just pointing to a new literal. Does the computer just remember that 3 + 1 is 4?

Comment: Generally speaking, the variable now simply contains 4, not 3+1.

Comment: Pick one language, they are very different. If you have a generic question then ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Generally scalar variables don't point to literals, they're just locations in memory that contain a value, changing the variable changes the value in memory, there's no change of pointers

Comment: "Literal" usually refers to some syntax for hardcoding a value into the code built into the language you're using. Languages usually have integral, floating point and string literals. It's left up for the compiler to figure out how to exactly store data at runtime, but you can be almost certain that the data is just stored as is in memory(register/RAM) and no pointers to shared storage are used. (These pointers would take up more memory than the data itself and degrade performance on access because of the indirection.)

Comment: Referring to java specifically: Note that there is a difference between `java.lang.Integer` and `int`. There are no literals of type `java.lang.Integer`, but there may be a literal converted to one in your code. Primitive types work a bit different than objects in java...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the word "literal" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485119/what-does-the-word-literal-mean)

Comment: Doing `x++` doesn't assign a new literal, it assigns a new _value_. The term literal only refers to occurrences of _literal_ values in the source code, that is a the characters `123` are a literal for the value `123`, while the characters `"a string"` are a literal for a string with the value `a string`, and `5.0` is a literal for a double (64-bit floating point) value, while `5.0f` is a literal for a float (32-bit floating point) value, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

x isn't a pointer.

The JVM spec just says what happens; *how* it happens is intentionally not specified. So, this answer merely explains how it works on all JVMs I'm aware of. Almost as good. It should certainly clarify matters:

```
class Example {
  int x = 3;

  void foo() {
    x++;
  }
}
```

Here, any time `new Example()` is executed, some block of memory is reserved for this instance. An instance of an object is simply a block of  memory that holds its basic properties (including that this is an object of type `Example`) and room to store the value of *every* non-static field. In this case, `int x` - that's a non-static field.

Primitives are special data types: It's a hard coded list: int, long, short, byte, double, float, boolean, and char. That's it. That's the whole list, you can't add any new types. They are 'special' - any value of a primitive type is just the value. **not a pointer**.

Thus, `int x = 3` means that any attempt to make a new Example instance (`new Example()`) will, as mentioned, reserve some space in memory to store the value of the `x` field, and that value is *directly* 3. It's not 'a pointer to a 3 object'. It's just.. 3. It'll take at least 32-bits (as `int` is 32 bits), it might effectively take 64 (CPUs pretty much require that objects are nicely aligned: That they start on a value that is divisible by 64, on 64-bit CPUs).

`x++` simply finds that memory position with the bit sequence 0000....0000011 (`0011` is binary for '3'), and increments it, turning that into 0000....0000100.

In contrast, let's try with an object - anything that isn't on that list of primitives is an object, and all such values *are* pointers. (In java speak, 'references'). So, in this very slightly changed code:

```
class Example {
  Integer x = 3;

  void foo() {
    x++;
  }
}
```

Something very very different is going on. For starters, auto-boxing: That is syntax sugar and is compiled as if you wrote:

```
class Example {
  Integer x = Integer.valueOf(3);

  void foo() {
    x = Integer.valueOf(x.intValue() + 1);
  }
}
```

Why? Because the JLS says so - that's what happens when you try to `x++` where `x` is a non-primitive type, *but*, is autoboxable to an `int`.

So, what happens here? Who knows? Who cares - the code of `valueOf` does what it does. It acts as the spec says it acts, it's generally not useful to ask *how*. But, if you're interested:

`Integer` (the class), upon loading (which it always will, as its such a core class) creates a 'cache', and makes 1 Integer object for each value between -128 and +127. `Integer.valueOf` will return you the value from the cache if possible (i.e. the argument you pass to it is between -128 and +127) otherwise it creates a new Integer object. Given that 3 and 4 fit, you get something like this:

```
package java.lang;

public class Integer {
  private static final Integer[] cache = new Integer[255];

  static {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      cache[i] = new Integer(i - 128);
    }
  }

  public static Integer valueOf(int v) {
    if (v >= -128 && v <= 127) return cache[v + 128];
    return new Integer(v);
  }

  private final int value;

  public Integer(int v) {
    this.value = v;
  }

  public int intValue() {
    return v;
  }
}
```

`x + 1` in java works because the spec says so. It doesn't have some lookup table that says '3 + 1 is 4', the concept of adding is baked into CPUs. Forget about pointers and such, computers are binary so numbers can only exist strictly in terms of zeroes and ones. Hence, even -1 is tricky (there's no '-'. Just zeroes and ones!). However, just because a number is stored in binary doesn't mean that adding is somehow impossible.

Given, say, 5 and 9:

- 5 = 00000101 in binary
- 9 = 00001001 in binary

to add them, you do the same thing you'd do when adding 2 decimal numbers. Add each element and make sure to carry any excess. So:

- the final digits are 1 and 1. Add those together: That's 0, carry the 1. We have: `???????0`
- The next two digits are 0 and 0. But we did have that carry, so, that's a 1. So far, we're at `??????10`.
- The 3rd digit from the left is 1 and 0. Add em up, that's a 1. We're at `?????110`.

... and so on. Arriving at `00001110`. There is no need for lookup tables to do this. Just a repeated application of this trivial table:

| carry-in | digit1 | digit2 | output | carry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

That logic (that 'table' + the logic to repeatedly apply it to every digit) is baked into the silicon of your CPU.